# How to get WordPress Media library Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want select image from media library, in my admin page, there I have list of items and its image, I want to change image of items using media library, this is my code

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this,'enqueue_media_lib'));
public function enqueue_media_lib(){
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_register_script( 'media-lib-uploader-js', plugins_url( 'js/media-library.js',dirname( __FILE__)), array('jquery'),'1.1.1',true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'media-lib-uploader-js' );
}

 <?php
      $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id,category, type,image_path, name, description FROM '.$ps_detail_table_name, ARRAY_A);
      foreach ($result as $value){ ?>
      <tr id="view-row<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
      <td id="view-category<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['category']; ?></td>
      <td id="view-type<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['type']; ?></td>
      <td id="view-name<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
      <td id="view-description<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['description']; ?></td>
      <td id="view-img-path<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
          <img id="product-img<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" src="<?php echo $value['image_path']; ?>" height="50px" width="50px"/>
          <input id="new_upload_image_button<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Change"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="new-image-attachment-id" id="new-image-attachment-id<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value=""/>
      </td>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var mediaUploader;

$('#new_upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    // If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (mediaUploader) {
        mediaUploader.open();
        return;
    }
    // Extend the wp.media object
    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        }, multiple: false });

    // When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('#new_upload_image_button').attr('src',attachment.url);
        $('#new-image-attachment-id').val(attachment.url);
    });
    // Open the uploader dialog
    mediaUploader.open();
});

});
```

This is my code I don't want to hardcore ID name in jQuery please give me solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
$("div[id^='new_upload_image_button']").click(function () {
      //mediaUploader code..
});
```

Comment: @DeekshithShetty the code will work if you have dynamic id's like  new_upload_image_button1, new_upload_image_button2 ....

Comment: if any number is missed then?

Comment: like after new_upload_image_button1, new_upload_image_button3, then is it work?

Comment: it takes the prefix div name new_upload_image_button , ya it should work !

Comment: @DeekshithShetty http://jsfiddle.net/bend92/s0yrjtc8/3/ refer the example

Comment: thanks for your solution ill try it, actually, now I solved that problem I gave a class to all button n fetched current id from class name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147608/discussion-between-ben-and-deekshith-shetty).